# Manipulate the form of a div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below code is a slider that manipulates between two dividers, previous and next. Each divider represents a set of ten images, as you can see in two parallel vertical lines. I'm trying to make each divider 2 parallel horizontal lines (5 images on each line), However it's getting messed up and the 2 dividers are getting connected. Any help please?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nav">
        <button id="prev" disabled>&lt;&lt;&lt;</button>
        <button id="next">&gt;&gt;&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <div id="mask">
        <div id="item1" class="item">
            <a name="item1"></a>
            <div class="content">
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="item2" class="item">
            <div class="content">
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
#prev {
  left: 40px;
}
#next {
  right: 40px;
}
#mask {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}    
.item {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.content img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
}
.content {
    width: 45%;
    height: 220px;
    top: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}       
.content a {
    position: relative;
    top: -17px;
    left: 170px;
}
.selected {
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"

$(document).ready(function () {
  function shift(direction) {
    var 
      $mask = $('#mask'),  
      items = $('.item').size(),
      currentItem = $mask.data('currentItem'),
      newItem;

    if (currentItem == undefined) {
      currentItem = 0;
    }

    newItem = currentItem + direction;
    $mask.data('currentItem', newItem).animate({marginLeft: -500 * newItem});

    if (newItem == 0) {
      $("#prev").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#prev").prop('disabled', false);
    }    
    if (newItem == items - 1) {
      $("#next").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#next").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  }

  $('#prev').click(function() {
    return shift(-1);
  });
  $('#next').click(function() {
    return shift(1);
  });
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/2ghovmww/

Comment: Your .content selector has a width of 45%.  If you want to enforce 5 and 5, you'll need to wrap them in divs likely and size them appropriately.

Comment: @Brian i tried to manipulate it but i ended up with the 2 dividers getting connected to each other somehow

Comment: @Anna said it better below.

Comment: @Brian i added the display inline, however what am i supposed to to manipulate after .. Now upon manipulating the width of .content, it's disappearing..

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you can achieve what you want with **display:inline** for each horizontal block, but as you have implemented it, the width of your container is smaller than the width of five elements in a row, so they can't be displayed. If you use overflow:hidden you will have two rows but the elements that exceed the width of the container will be hidden. So first you must adjust the width of the container and its parent elements.

Comment: to what measures you need to manipulate the width of the container? it's not working

Comment: what I am saying is start from the begging and traverse through the hierarchy of your divs. For example your wrapper is 500px and the mask inside is 5000px! also, since you need 5 imgs in a row the content must be at least 5*100(width of img)  while yours is 0.45*500.